# print a character in the usb-serial port

Tags: usb, python, linux

Hello everybody and thank you for all the answers that you give me to solve this problems.

Someone said me: This code print a word that I choose in the screen, but **How to send or print an ASCII character by the usb-serial port?**

```
import serial

port =serial.Serial(
    "/dev/ttyUSB0",
    baudrate=57600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    writeTimeout = 0,
    timeout = 10,
    rtscts=False,
    dsrdtr=False,
    xonxoff=False)

data=bytes([0x0c,0x80,0x09,0x00,0xf0,0xce,0x61,0x9d,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00]) 

print(port.isOpen()) 
print("Port opened...") 
port.write(data) 
print("Data sent")

while True:
    print("inside while")
    response=port.read(8)
    print(response)
    print ("Data Received")
    break
```

This code is of **hsantana8**

I appreciate of the help that you can give.

Answer (score 2):

You shoule be able to send any ASCII Sequence by writing

```
port.write('Hello World\n')
```

instead of

```
port.write(data)
```

the `\n` is a newline character which is often used as a statement terminator. Depending on your device on the other end, you may also have to use `\r\n`, `\r` or similar.

Also see [this](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html).